SKUs have hyphens will searches find product if they do not use hyphens in search?
We have SKU's with 'hyphens' for example: 123-123-123
Because these are rare SKUs when someone searches using Google the product is found... But what happens if someone searches for sku: 123123123 i.e without hyphens?
Will Google find the same product?
Or should I duplicate the SKU on the single product page, but without Hyphens, so something like this
123-123-123 (123123123)

Are you leveraging Product schema on these pages and leveraging the sku parameter? I did a quick test with a couple SKUs for t-shirts and removing the hyphens greatly impacted the results: only hyphens returned the correct products.  If this is an existing site, how do your user typically search; hyphens or no hyphens?

Hi
The visitors will search with and without hyphens and yes we will use Product Schema

You could maybe try to pass a list in the sku. Something like sku:[123456,123-456] however I don't know if this is valid syntax. Definitely test it out.

I conducted a test with rich snippet and it passes when you use a list for the sku parameter. https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=HrA2LDUV4WXK7atK8UbMBA. Also, if your users use both, it would probably be important to make sure you reference both hyphen and non-hyphen SKUs in the page content as well.

Sorry for the delay, so SKU with Hyphen and then place SKU on product page without SKU?

For the on page content, you could list it as "product 123-456 (123456)" and in your schema, you could use a list for the sku key like I showed in the above. To will need to list both ways of writing it if you want out to be indexable for each.
